# What does "boys rule, girls drool" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, figurative-language

What does "Boys rule, girls drool," mean? I googled it but did not get a straightforward answer.

It is a dialogue of *Dumb And Dumber* (2014) film.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is an example of "playground language". It is the sort of thing that boys might say on the school playground, when they think no adults can hear them.  It is a childish insult.

Saying "*something* rules" means you think that thing is great. This is a fairly common slang.

> I love *Game of Thrones*.  I think it *rules*.

On the other hand, to "drool" is when spit and saliva drips out of your mouth. You might drool when you see delicious food, but we say that someone who drools all the time must be a dirty and stupid person.

Specifically, the rule/drool pattern (and this use of the word rule in general) was popular among kids sometime around the late 80s or early to mid 90s. I'm not sure if it's entirely gone out of use since then, but it's less common. It wasn't specific to genders but any pair of things perceived as having a rivalry (or rivalry between their fans).

So the whole phrase means "Boys are great! Girls are stupid!"  It isn't a very subtle message, but kids love rhyme and kids love being rude.

Adults would never usually say this – unless they were deliberately trying to sound childish for humorous effect. It is sexist and rude. It is in the film as a joke to show that the character is very childish.

Comment: You might be interested to know, I [posted a related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/512560/who-ruled-first-girls-or-boys) on EL&U.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm pretty sure the more common usage of this phrase has the genders the other way around.  This may be part of the joke.

Comment: The fact that this phrases uses two rhyming words is a big part of why it exists

Comment: Specifically, the *rule/drool* pattern (and this use of the word *rule* in general) was popular among kids sometime around the late 80s or early to mid 90s. I'm not sure if it's entirely gone out of use since then, but it's less common. It wasn't specific to genders but any pair of things perceived as having a rivalry (or rivalry between their fans).

Comment: 'drool' can also mean 'to talk nonsense', not necessarily to be stupid.

Comment: You say "adults would usually never say this", but "EEs [electrical engineers] rule. MEs [mechanical engineers] drool" used to be a slogan around my office. (Not that it was used unironically, but anyway)

Comment: @Darrel Hoffman: I'm probably biased having been surrounded by girls growing up, but I can attest having heard it the other way around.

Comment: @ThePhoton - That's an interesting comment. I guess what this answer really meant to say was: _Adults would never usually say this – unless they were deliberately trying to sound childish for humorous effect._

Answer (score 1):

The original phrase was also the opposite: Girls rule, boys drool. The opposite use in Dumb And Dumber is meant to suggest the characters' immaturity and stupidity in a "I know what you are but what am I / I'm rubber you're glue, whatever you say bounces off me and sticks to you" sense.